# jQuery + PHP + JavaScript + Wordpress: HTML Button call on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Ok, so I've read countless attempted answers on similar problems, but for whatever reason they're not working for me.  I have a WordPress site and I'm attempting to make a plugin that needs jQuery.

First, there's my wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/index.php page:

```
    <?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' ); 

    function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('TestFile', plugins_url('/js/TestFile.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', false);
    }
    ...
function printButton(){
echo '<input type ="button" id="myButton" name="myButton" value="My Button"/>';
}
```

I call printButton about a dozen times in the code, and I've checked the HTML to ensure that it spits out as written.  If a user clicks any of the dozen buttons, I want the same jQuery call to run.  I've also made sure that jquery itself is enqueued in the header file for WordPress, so it definitely knows that jQuery exists.  When I do an Inspect Element view, the console spits out no errors when I click.

Then there's my TestFile.js file:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#myButton').click(function(e){
    alert("Button Clicked!");
    });
  });
```

I know I should be able to use '$' instead of 'jQuery', but for whatever reason WordPress is being stupid.  So from everything I've read, this is pretty straightforward stuff and I should get a pretty little alert popup whenever I click any of my buttons.  Sadly, nothing happens when I click...

Ideas?  Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Do you realize you create a dozen or so elements with the same id, and that the id is supposed to be unique? I am not sure if that is the cause of this problem, but by doing so you enter the space of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh... I'm not sure if that is causing the problem.  Going back to check.

Comment: I would recommend doing `console.log( jQuery('#myButton') );` just before you attach the click handler, then checking which elements were matched. Could it be that the html with the buttons is loaded dynamically using ajax, and are not there yet when calling that piece of code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Your ID should be unique.
2. Try to use `jQuery(selector).on( ... );`

Comment: `jQuery.on(..)` is not a function.

Comment: Please note that this answer does not work, even though it has been accepted. The correct syntax is `jQuery(selector).on( ... );`. The first selector is usually document/body, the second selector is on which elements it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind the action to an ID, bind it to a class.

The ID must be unique to an element. If you have a dozen buttons all with `id='myButton'`, then none of them will be bound correctly by jQuery.

Instead, bind to a class designation like:

```
function printButton(){
    echo '<input type ="button" class="aButton" name="myButton" value="My Button"/>';
}
```

Then the jQuery would read

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.myButton').click(function(e){
    alert("Button Clicked!");
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for the class. Considering "myButton" to be the desired name as in jQuery-function change the class in "function printButton" to:

```
function printButton(){
    echo '<input type ="button" class="myButton" name="myButton" value="My Button"/>';
}
```